# marshal.PtrToStructure access violation exception

Tags: c#, exception, marshalling

I have a struct defined as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1)]
    private struct networkMessage
        {
        public messageType type;
        public string message;
        }
```

and I have this function to convert the struct into `byte[]`

```
private byte[] ConvertToByteArray(networkMessage inStruct)
        {
        int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(inStruct);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[structSize];

        IntPtr memPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
            {
            memPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(inStruct, memPtr, false);
            Marshal.Copy(memPtr, byteArray, 0, structSize);
            }
        finally
            {
            if (memPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memPtr);
                }
            }
        foreach (byte b in byteArray)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(b + " ");
            }

        return byteArray;
        }
```

and this to convert back into a struct

```
private networkMessage ConvertFromByteArray(byte[] inByte)
        {
        foreach (byte b in inByte)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            }

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(inByte, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        networkMessage outStruct = (networkMessage) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(networkMessage));  //---Exception here

        return outStruct;
        }
```

This in use for a TCP application which both acts as a server and client, such that the same executable runs on both machines. Testing the conversion in the objects constructor shows it working fine, but a byte array coming from another computer causes an access violation exception. Printing out the bytes on both systems shows they are the same. What could be the problem? I assume this might have something to do with the struct?

Comment: This should always crash.  The *message* field is missing the required [MarshalAs] attribute to declare it ByValTStr, needs SizeConst as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work.

Try this: Set `message` to a string much longer than 16 characters and then look at the value of `Marshal.SizeOf(inStruct)`. It will be 12 for a 64-bit version and 8 for a 32 bit version - regardless of the length of `message`.

The correct solution to this is to use serialization to convert the data.

You might want to check out [`NetTcpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can use [DataContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize the data.

Also, have a look at [JSON serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).